# What are the most common optimization algorithms for confirmatory factor analysis?

Tags: confirmatory-factor

For confirmatory factor analysis, as I understand it, we have  the following set up:

[image]
Source: Sacha Epskamp’s lecture notes

I then read that some authors have tried the following approaches

[image]

Source: A First Course in Factor Analaysis by Comrey, Lee

I was wondering if Fletcher-Powell or Newton-Raphson are commonly used? If not, what’s th most common way people optimize their loss function in CFA?

Comment: With Newton-Raphson, you have to know the derivatives, which may or may not be complex for CFA; I never used their SEM program for CFA so I don't know the derivatives.   With the increased computational speed of most computers nowadays, there would have to be a lot of papers on use of metaheuristics to solve these optimizations through a derivative-free approach.  But if the derivatives are known, Newton-Raphson will probably be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The Newton-Raphson requires calculation of the second derivatives which are cumbersome to compute.  However, the first derivatives are readily available (see Stanley Muliak's book on Factor Analysis) so quasi-newton methods like Fletcher-Powell or BGFS should work well.